# Android getSupportLoaderManager() is undefined for the type Activity

Tags: android, cursoradaper, loader

Здравствуйте, вопрос по андроид на тему `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Следующей строкой 
`getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, getActivity());`
я хочу запустить
`public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle)`,
но на `getSupportLoaderManager()` есть красная линия и следующая ошибка:

`The method getSupportLoaderManager() is undefined for the type Activity`.

Сам клас он фрагмент, если нужно могу опубликовать весь код.
Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

метод `getSupportLoaderManager()` определен только в классе [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)  и его наследниках. Чтобы его вызвать, Вам надо "привести" Activity к этому типу.

Comment: спасибо )))))))))

Comment: скажите пожалуйста если я использую CursorAdapter то на это строку getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this); на initLoader появляется следующая ошибка The method initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>) in the type LoaderManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, null, TableFragment) в чем проблема  ??

Comment: решение проблемы http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155753/getloadermanager-initloader-doesnt-accept-this-as-argument-though-the-cla